# cómo Obtener el índice de un caracter de un string

Tags: javascript

Estoy aprendiendo sobre cómo obtener el índice de un caracter de un string.

Tengo este ejemplo, pero no entiendo de dónde sale "`Blute`", ¿cómo se obtiene "`returns -1`"?

Tampoco entiendo la 4ta línea:

```
"Blue Whale".indexOf("Whale",5) // returns 5
```

¿Cómo se obtiene "`returns 5`"?.

Por favor su ayuda. Gracias.

Ejemplo:

```
"Blue Whale".indexOf("Blue")    // returns 0
"Blue Whale".indexOf("Blute")   // returns -1
"Blue Whale".indexOf("Whale",0) // returns 5
"Blue Whale".indexOf("Whale",5) // returns 5
"Blue Whale".indexOf("",9)      // returns 9
"Blue Whale".indexOf("",10)     // returns 10
"Blue Whale".indexOf("",11)     // returns 10
```

El método indexOf es sensible a mayúsculas. Por ejemplo, la siguiente expresión devuelve -1:

```
"Ballena Azul".indexOf("azul")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comento lo siguiente

El método indexOf() lee la cadena de texto como un array y como ya sabras en cualquier lenguaje los arrays se leen de este modo:

> array = [0,1,2,3,4]

Donde cada uno de los números son las posiciones que ocuparán los elementos que tu le declaras

```
"Blue Whale".indexOf("Blute")
```

> El método indexOf buscará en la cadena original la coincidencia de la
>   cadena final que le pasas; retorna -1 cuando no encuentra dicha
>   coincidencia; por eso puedes notar que Blue no es igual que Blute lo
>   cual el método indexOf() retornará como -1 indicandote que de las 2
>   cadenas que pasaste no existen coincidencias entre ellas

```
"Blue Whale".indexOf("Whale",5)
```

Devuelve 5 por que toma la cadena de texto completa incluyendo espacios en blanco y los lee como un array, si haces el conteo la letra **W** empieza en la posición 5

> Del mismo modo si dicho método es sensible a mayúsculas

Comment: y en este caso:                                                                         
"Blue Whale".indexOf("",10)     // returns 10    
(sale returns 10 porque no eciste el carcater 10?)
"Blue Whale".indexOf("",11)     // returns 10  (aqui por qué sal returns 10, no debería salir 11, ya que no existe ni el 10 ni el 11?                                    
Soy nueva  nueva en esto, no sé absolutamente nada de string. Mil gracias!!

"Ballena Azul".indexOf("azul")

Comment: exacto es sensible a mayúsculas y los 2 anteriores te devuelven 10 por que le estás indicando que busque en la cadena de texto donde no haya espacio en blanco y si te das cuenta justo despues de Whale no hay espacio entre las comillas y la palabra por eso te retorna eso por que es el final de la cadena o array y cumple la condición aunque en teoría el array solo tiene 9 posiciones

Comment: Gracias Shadow!

Comment: disculpa, me acabo de dar cuenta que sólo se puede aceptar una rpta. Es verdad, tu rpta. esta más completa. Slds.

Answer (score 1):

```
"Blue Whale".indexOf("Blute") // returns -1
```

Esta linea significa que "Blute" no existe en la string, por eso retorna -1.

```
"Blue Whale".indexOf("Whale") // return 5
```

Esta linea nos dice que la palabra "Whale" inicia en la posicion 5 de la string